# How can I implement search functionality with a prefix highlighting in a non-editable ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, combobox

I want to create combo which is only allows selection from a fixed list but has search functionality like an editable combo i.e. when you type the combo searches for items which match the prefix you typed and the text after the prefix is highlighted in the selection box.

I think I can implement the necessary logic to do the searching but I don't know how to get the highlighting to work. I guess I could compose combo items out of text blocks and use and back colour to implement highlighting but the item would somehow need to know it is being rendered in the selection box, not the drop down area.
With IsEditable=false there is some prefix search functionality but it's transient - if you don't type anything for a second or two the prefix is reset. For this to be usable the user needs to see what he has typed and edit the prefix using backspace if needed so highlighting of the prefix is important.

The combo may have many long items and I want the user to have to time find the items he wants. Setting IsEditable to true gives more or less the search behavior I want but I don't want the user to be able type text in the box which doesn't match any item.

I have looked into customizing an editable combo to only accept key presses which match items in the list and had a degree of success but I don't want the selection behaviour of an editable combo - see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442021/how-can-i-customize-an-editable-wpf-combo-to-prevent-changing-the-selected-value

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox will show the first matching entry even if `IsEditable="False"`.

The problem you have might be a fixed list with multiple entries starting with the same. For example:

```
AAAA
AACC
BBBB
```

In this case you could give each entry a unique key:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AAAA" TextSearch.Text="A" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="BBBB" TextSearch.Text="B" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AACC" TextSearch.Text="C" />
</ComboBox>
```

Then if you type **C** key **AACC** entry will be selected.

Comment: Thank for this but it doesn't quite do what I want - visual highlighting of the seach prefix is an important part of waht I need - have updated the question.